# Writing a function to initialize classes with uncertain input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have three classes that receive input in similar ways, but each class takes a different number of arguments. So, class 1 has 7 arguments in its init function, class 2 has 4, and class 3 has 5, and I'd like to make a function that can initialize any one of them. How should I go about doing this? Normally I would take the list of parameters, p[0], p[1], etc., and feed them in as arguments to the class, but with an uncertain amount of input, I'm not sure how I can do this.

Comment: Any code examples what you have and try to achieve?

Comment: The usual way would be to use `*args`. See [Arbitrary Argument Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) in the tutorial. Without seeing some sample code it's hard to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without judging your design concepts, I reckon a plausible way to achieve this is by writing a function with a variable number of `args` and checking against their length, i.e:

```
def initializer(*args):
    num_args = len(args)
    if num_args == 7:
        return Class1(*args)
    elif num_args == 5:
        return Class3(*args)
    elif num_args == 4:
        return Class2(*args)
    else:
        # handle this unsupported scenario
```

Handling error cases accordingly.

With some sample classes:

```
class Class3:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d, e):
        print(a, b, c, d, e)

class Class2:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d):
        print(a, b, c, d)

class Class1:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d, e, f, g):
        print(a, b, c, d, e, f, g)
```

you'd get the required effect:

```
>>> initializer(1, 2, 3, 4)
1 2 3 4
<__main__.Class2 at 0x7fe8e450ed68>
>>> initializer(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
1 2 3 4 5
<__main__.Class3 at 0x7fe8e450ee80>
>>> initializer(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
<__main__.Class1 at 0x7fe8e450e518>
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I'm still learning and had not heard of *args, this solves my problem perfectly.